# Requirements management plugin for Trac?

Tags: trac, requirements

Are there any requirements management plugins out there for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)? I checked the list on [Trac-Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) and didn't see anything

I'm picturing some functionality like [IBM's DOORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/doors/) system. Basic features include revisioning and change control of requirements, requirements baselining etc.

**Update:** I suppose I could just use the wiki portion of Trac to document requirements, but this doesn't allow anykind of change sets for the requirements - for example where a single requirement has changed but developers are working against a baseline where the requirement hasn't been updated yet. It also won't allow linking requirements such that when a parent requirement changes, all dependent requirements must be reviewed before the change is accepted (in order to keep dependent requirements in sync).

Comment: Its a feature that I see a lot of requests for on the Trac mailing list.  There is a dotProject integration for Trac, but I haven't evaluated it yet, and to my knowledge dotProject is more project management than requirements tracking. You might take a look at: http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/1226

Comment: If you could have different work-flows based on the ticket type you could create a requirements ticket and use that for requirements management. This would be a nice-to-have feature for Trac that I've seen in other systems.

Comment: @TheTodd: using either the AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin or another one on trac-hacks, you can make your workflow depend on the type of the ticket.

Comment: @retracile: Thanks, I'll check that out. There are so many plug-ins available on trac-hacks it's hard to find the ones that will work for a particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

@retracile: thanks for this "how to". I just discovered [rmtoo](http://rmtoo.florath.net/) which does text based requirements management... and btw, looking back to it, it has also VCS integration features and, as Trac, is written in Python.

Answer (score 2):

When you start talking about revisioning of your requirements, I think you really need to step back and look at your requirements as part of your source tree.  Find a file format for the requirements that an SCM can handle (text-based, etc), and just check them in.  Treat them as the early part of your code... when it's time to figure out what the requirements will be for v2.0, create your v2.0 branch and develop the requirements on that branch, and follow it with your code development on that same branch.

If you use branch-based development, create the requirements on the branch, create the code on the same branch, and then merge the branch.  That keeps requirements and implementation in sync.

Comment: Not a bad idea. And I have thought about using SCM for requirements. However, not all users creating requirements have the technical ability to use SCM software. In particular business analysts.

Comment: Some of them will have the technical ability to use it; some will have the intelligence and willingness to learn to use it; and others... I'd assign a "secretary" to them to handle it for them.  (Instead of handling the typing, handle the SCM.)  Something like webDAV so you could point them to a "network drive" _might_ provide a partial technical solution for them, but it has its own quirks.